# unparse js Date to local time string via cljs-time

Tags: datetime, clojurescript

it's 15:51 here.

Well, in UTF it's 13:51. I'm trying to unparse the current local hours by the help of the cljs-time library.

Here's the non-local approach:

```
(require [cljs-time.format :as tf]
         [cljs-time.coerce :as tc])

(tf/unparse (tf/formatter "HH") (tc/from-date (js/Date.)))
;; 13
```

Unfortunately the following produces the same result and not the desired 15:

```
(tf/unparse-local (tf/formatter-local "HH") (tc/from-date (js/Date.)))
```

Does anybody know, what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

By default, `cljs-time` works via `goog.date.UtcDateTime`, which returns UTC hours and minutes.

`unparse-local` and `formatter-local` just remove the time zone field from the format string. They do not affect the time zone.

To work with the local (default) time, `goog.date.DateTime`, you can use `cljs-time.core/to-default-time-zone`:

```
(require '[cljs-time.core :as time]
         '[cljs-time.format :as fmt])

(tf/unparse (tf/formatter "HH") (time/to-default-time-zone (js/Date.)))
```

This should return your local time in hours.